# nearest value of a integer value with javascript or make round figure with javascript

Tags: javascript, integer, settimeout

I am using a javascript countdown function to display the time inside a textbox named sec

and i have two buttons there prev and next i want to minus 10 numbers if i press prev button and add 10 numbers if i click on next button the script is fine and calculating the numbers perfectly but i need the added number change to a round figure like if the sec value is 56 and i click on prev button so the minus value will be 46 but i need it to change 40. so as with the next button if the sec is 46 its will add 10 number and it become 56 but i need it 60 from this how to do? here is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var t;

function countdown()
{
    $('#sec').val(parseInt($('#sec').val()) + 1);
    t = setTimeout("countdown();",1000);
    sec = document.getElementById('sec');
    if($('#sec').val()>=1 && $('#sec').val()<10)    {$('.thought').load('somefile.php?limit=0');    }
    else if($('#sec').val()>=10 && $('#sec').val()<20){$('.thought').load('somefile.php?limit=1');}
    else if($('#sec').val()>=20 && $('#sec').val()<30){$('.thought').load('somefile.php?limit=2');}
    else if($('#sec').val()>=30 && $('#sec').val()<40){$('.thought').load('somefile.php?limit=3');}
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    countdown();
    $('.thought_prev_btn').click(function(){
        var second = Math.floor(parseInt($('#sec').val()) - 10);
        $('#sec').val(second);
     });
});
</script>
```

i have used `math.floor()` function but that works with only decimal value

Comment: ((num - decrement) / decrement) * decrement), You can use Math.max function to set a minimum value

Comment: Just and idea. You can try converting it to decimal point (eg. divide by 10) and use the Math.floor() function for when you need the lower value, and Math.ceil() for when you need the higher value, and then multiplying it back by 10.

Comment: thanks Dzulqarnain your trick works i have made the decimal value first then convert that with Math.floor()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `floor` and `ceil` with any precision other than units, divide by the relevant power of ten, then multiply again afterwards. I like to use these helper functions:

```
function floor(num,power) {
    var p = Math.pow(10,power||0);
    return Math.floor(num/p)*p;
}
```

`function ceil` is similar, just with `Math.ceil` instead of `Math.floor`.

Then I can call, for example, `floor(123,1)` and I'll get `120`.
`floor(12345,3)` will return `12000`.
`floor(12.345,-1)` will return `12.3`

Basically the second argument is the number of positions to the left of the decimal point the number should be cut off at.

Comment: i am having two digit number for that how do i do?